# GitLab CI yml file using Poetry, Python, Linux

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using following yml file

```
image: python:latest

stages:
  - install
  - lint
  - test

before_script:
  - python --version ; pip --version  # For debugging

# install dependencies and create virtual environment
install_dependencies:
  stage: install
  script:
    - pip install poetry
    - poetry install  # it creates virtual environment too

# run pre-commit checks
pre-commit:
  stage: lint
  script:
    - poetry run pre-commit run --all-files

# test the code
pytest:
  stage: test
  script:
    - poetry run pytest
```

install stage go as expected by than on lint stage i got an error

```
$ poetry run pre-commit run --all-files
/bin/bash: line 127: poetry: command not found
```

but i have poetry installed on my linux-mint virtual machine.
how do i properly write this yml file so the pre-commit hooks will be checked and pytest will be run?

Comment: The `install_dependencies` and `commit` jobs do not run on the same image, be it local runner or gitlab runner. You need to run `pip install poetry` in every job. Use `before_script`

Comment: YML is a derivative from XML and pre-dates YAML, which is what you seem to have. On to the yaml.org FAQ the recommened extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006

Comment: @DeepSpace it worked. though is installing it before every script optimal? it will take some time doing the same task over and over.